# What are the benefits of extending LinearLayout over View?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view

I am trying to build a soundboard app that plays a sound whenever you tap on a custom view. In order to organize my UI, I used a layout file.

When I extended `View`, I found that when I tried to inflate my layout, it wouldn't work.

```
//Didn't work
View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.sound_view_layout, null);
```

When I extended `LinearLayout`, however, it did work.

```
//Worked
View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.sound_view_layout, this);
```

**My question is**,

how come I needed to extend a Layout class in order for the program to work, and what are the benefits of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can only inflate a layout.  If you want to just create a View, use `new CustomView(context)`.

Ignoring that-  the main reason to extend a layout is if you want to add children to it programmatically, or if its a collection of views already (for example you may want to create a view CaptionedPhoto that has an image on top of text.  One way to do this would be to make CaptionedPhoto extend LinearLayout and hold an image view and a text view).